# How to progress Android's GradientDrawable to transparent endColor more quickly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

In the following code example, a gradient is being used to generate a shadow background on a rectangle shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:startColor="#8f000000"
    />
</shape>
```

This gradient progresses from startColor to endColor too slowly. (It is 50% transparent when it is 50% of the way through the gradient and 75% transparent when 75% of the way through the gradient.)

I want this gradient to progress more quickly than 50/50 or 75/75. For instance, it would be nice to have the gradient 75% transparent when only 50% of the way through the gradient's background shape.

Which property 'speeds up' gradient diffusion for Android's GradientDrawable XML class?

Answer (score 1):

I have a small hack around this. You can try to add this attribute to your existing code and give it the same color as startColor or endColor to make the gradient progress quickly.

```
 android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: hey at least it helps :)